# Using Java to establish a secure connection to MySQL Amazon RDS (SSL/TLS)

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I am trying to securely connect to Amazon RDS using JDK 1.8 and MySQL Connector/J version 5.1.23 and I am confused about the instructions in [MySQL Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html).

The instructions say to create a truststore in the current directory and import the server's CA certificate. When I run the below command I am asked for a password and I do not know what to enter:

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file file_location.pem -keystore truststore
```

The [instructions from Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) on the other hand point out that certificates are signed by a certificate authority. The SSL certificate includes the DB instance endpoint as the Common Name (CN). The public key is also stored at http://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.

Whilst I understand the concept of SSL/TSL and private/public keys, I am confused how to implement this?

When I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';` command I receive "yes" as a value. When I am connected to the database and run `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version';`, I receive no value back.

How do you establish a secure connection from Java to a MySQL database?

**Update:**
I am using ubuntu and I used the keytool to generate a `truststore.jks` file in the JRE directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/`. I also executed the following command: `GRANT USAGE ON db_name.* To 'username'@'address' REQUIRE SSL;`

The below code is how I am connecting to the database:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class mainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/truststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststore_password");

        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql_rds_enpoint:port/db_name?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";

        Connection mysqlConnection = null;
        mysqlConnection = (Connection) mysqlMethods.connectToMysql(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

The above code produces a `Communications link failure` message and `The last packet successfully received from the server was 24 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 24 milliseconds ago`. I am able to successfully connect when `?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true` is removed from the uri and `REQUIRE SSL` is removed from the user permissions.

**Update 2:**
I have taken the code back to basics and when I run the below code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class testClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/truststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststore_password");

        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql_rds_enpoint:port/db_name?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
        final String username = "username";
        final String password = "password";

        try {
            Object connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 206 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 203 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:110)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4760)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2239)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at apples.main(mainClass.java:18)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:95)
    ... 18 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:90)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1488)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    ... 20 more

Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
    at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:88)
    ... 32 more
```

I have also confirmed using Workbench and the .pem file that the user is able to login using SSL.

**Update 3:** Debug info after setting javax.net.debug to ssl:

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/truststore.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=aws.amazon.com/rds/, OU=RDS, O=Amazon.com, L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=aws.amazon.com/rds/, OU=RDS, O=Amazon.com, L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xe775b657e21a8128
  Valid from Tue Apr 06 08:44:31 AEST 2010 until Sun Apr 05 08:44:31 AEST 2015

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1425012760 bytes = { 250, 182, 202, 168, 139, 248, 125, 121, 251, 188, 182, 110, 1, 234, 29, 105, 158, 219, 212, 122, 105, 57, 87, 80, 44, 141, 121, 154 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=abcd.abcd123.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 202
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 74
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1571637097 bytes = { 78, 228, 80, 30, 162, 233, 208, 59, 196, 166, 88, 129, 155, 99, 123, 252, 123, 153, 129, 25, 144, 235, 185, 112, 68, 79, 2, 79 }
Session ID:  {104, 7, 155, 31, 238, 102, 222, 218, 193, 219, 108, 206, 57, 235, 53, 253, 1, 200, 64, 46, 92, 60, 63, 251, 142, 106, 233, 54, 27, 110, 79, 128}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1057
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Seattle, O=Amazon.com, OU=RDS, CN=sifrmedium.cove4uttgoa2.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 7182371456073335432842458631460148573771628715802835656528548198324749485547005738326606223242830258829871966755842342342342344059076665280539770508892924695580383343581127930380098999434723444448883595421930164673020286553920728427
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sun Jun 21 11:55:57 AEST 2015,
               To: Fri Mar 06 09:03:24 AEDT 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Amazon RDS ap-southeast-2 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    810c7b2c 621bcf07 366cad3b ab405b]

Certificate Extensions: 2
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 89 50 9D 8D 0A 1D 42 A7   D6 36 2E 99 27 44 61 FC  .P.......6..'Ia.
0010: 23 FC D7 F0                                        #...
]
[CN=Amazon RDS Root CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US]
SerialNumber: [    46]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0C 5C 64 D5 CE C4 27 13   34 01 A0 0D 64 8C B1 C9  .\d...'.4...d<..
0010: 4D 6C 3D 16                                        M\=.
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 16 53 AA 7A 55 49 84 87   5C EC 49 B9 BD 51 98 83  .S.zUI..\.I..Q..
0010: BA 91 84 72 29 77 19 6C   F7 CA 0A 36 09 AC 70 F4  ...r)w.l...6..p.
0020: 8A 2C 90 FD 36 3D 3D CD   E9 BA 2C 5C 95 C3 79 78  .,..6==...,\..yx
0030: CE FA 46 A0 3D 77 31 11   E3 5B 9C 84 AF 4D 60 51  ..F.=w1..[...M`Q
0040: 80 52 04 1E 65 4D 6E 5B   92 E1 69 79 12 8E 56 0F  .R..eMn[..iy..V.
0050: 83 E4 F8 31 4E A7 65 4E   C2 BB 97 A8 B4 67 79 F4  ...1N.eN.....gy.
0060: CD 37 F7 00 A5 42 B9 E0   CB D9 CA 81 EC E3 A3 E3  .7...B..........
0070: FB 05 40 2F 9A 4B 5D AE   7C 30 F4 BA ED DC 74 AC  ..@/.K]..0....t.
0080: 89 30 AD 13 26 F7 88 09   66 01 E1 4B 3A 8C B1 3D  .0..&...f..K:..=
0090: 28 6F 74 1D B0 00 25 FB   9B 1E 00 8D F1 1F 83 84  (ot...%.........
00A0: CE D7 92 39 78 C4 70 26   8E 3C 05 1C 10 3C A3 E0  ...9x.p&.<...<..
00B0: CC 30 F0 A0 68 B1 26 C4   23 AC C0 C6 8A 27 DB 3C  .0..h.&.#....'.<
00C0: 7F 38 DD EE 92 1B A3 A4   99 13 9F 80 62 66 C8 F0  .8..........bf..
00D0: 46 25 38 C3 99 0A A2 A7   04 E5 FF 4D 31 2B E4 82  F%8........M1+..
00E0: BE D9 D5 07 28 96 17 07   30 B9 EC BA 26 F3 7B C3  ....(...0...&...
00F0: 1A CF 13 73 58 96 F2 87   3F FD 86 09 35 FA A3 7B  ...sX...?...5...

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: Most of the answer may be useful: [How to connect to a remote MySQL database via SSL using Play Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27536391).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed the link and created a truststore.jks file and appened `?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true"` to the default url. 

When I change the database url, I am no longer able to connect to MySQL. I noticed that the linked instructions were for the 'Play Framework', is the command `keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -keystore truststore.jks` valid for normal Java applications? 

Also where is the .jks file meant to be located within the project?

Comment: The keytool command will work for you even without play framework.  By default Java uses cacerts.jks within the JRE directory, but you can specify whatever location you with from the code using appropriate SSL classes.  Can you show your code for connecting to the mySQL server?  It looks like you are trying to use an HTTP style URL, and that's now how database connections work.

Comment: I updated the ticket to include the code used to connect. I use the endpoint for the instance to connect which is in the form `abcd.abcd123.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Do you set the following system properties: `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` when you start your JVM?. Also remember to set the user account with the option `REQUIRE SSL`. e.g.: `GRANT USAGE ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost' REQUIRE SSL;`.

Comment: I have now added the trustStore system properties and made sure that the user requires SSL however I am still not able to connect and receive the same response. I updated the post to reflect the changes.

Comment: The trustAnchors error messages in the exceptions suggest there's a problem with the CA certificates: they're either missing, not being correctly referenced or the trust store contains the wrong certs. Try setting the Java system property "javax.net.debug" to "ssl" : this should give you some more detailed error messages.

Comment: @alphaloop Thanks for the advice, I updated the ticket with the ssl debug information.

Comment: I also used the following command `keytool -list  -v -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/truststore.jks` to confirm that the keystore contains 1 entry.

Comment: I ran into a problem with the amazon combined pem, followed the leads here and still go the error about the path not in the chain, but that cleared up when I set verifyServerCertificate to false... fyi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you run the below command and are asked for the password you should type "changeit". That is the default password for the keystore

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file file_location.pem -keystore truststore
```

Next, make sure the mysql user you are using is configured to require SSL as below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'root'@'localhost' REQUIRE SSL;
```

Next, make sure the rds bundle which you downloaded from  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem is imported on the default java cacerts of the app server which is trying to connect to the AWS RDS.

Lastly, you need append the below three properties with value 'true' to your mysql url

```
?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

Eg:

```
final String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql_rds_enpoint:port/db_name?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't the URL also need to have `&clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:...&clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=...` in it?

Answer (score 10):

Java keytool only imports one certificate at a time, but the RDS combined CA bundle has many CA certificates. You will need to import each certificate in the bundle separately. When you try to import the bundle, it is only importing one certificate, which may not be the root CA that you need to trust the RDS instance.

On linux you can split the pem with the CSPLIT tool:

```
csplit -b %02d.pem -z rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem /-----BEGIN/ {*}
```

Then you must import each pem into your keystore separately.

Comment: how to decide which pem file to use and set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` path

Comment: @RahulGoyal You import every pem into a single keystore (say trust.jks), and set your trustStore path to that keystore (trust.jks).

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS X, MidnightBSD, and FreeBSD, the procedure is similar.  This will break up and import all of the certificates from the rds-combined-cabundle.pem.  You will need to change the path for OS X, but otherwise it's identical.

```
split -p "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem individual-

find . -iname 'individual*' -exec keytool -import -file {} -alias {} -storepass changeit -keystore /usr/local/openjdk8/jre/lib/security/cacerts \;
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS provides separate certificates and not just the bundle, which has extra stuff you won't need. (As mentioned by others, importing large numbers of certificates via keytool is a pain.) See [Using SSL to Encrypt a Connection to a DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html).

You will need to download two certificates: the root certificate, and the intermediate certificate for your region. As stated in the link above,

> A root certificate that works for all regions can be downloaded at
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem.

and the intermediate cerificates can be found further down the page. You must use the one appropriate for your region, the region where your database instance is located.

I recommend using keytool to import both of these into a new keystore, and tell MySQL to use that keystore via the `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl` and `trustCertificateKeyStorePassword` connection parameters. Messing with the main keystore can be a little risky.

Answer (score 2):

RDS pem file importer script.
This script can be used to split and import RDS certs automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
truststore_import() {
[ $# -eq 0 ] && echo 'args <cert-file> <storepass> <keystore-path>' && return 1

CERTFILE=${1:-rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem}
STOREPASS=${2:changeit}
KEYSTORE=${3:-/etc/ssl/truststore.jks}

TEMPDIR=`mktemp -d`

csplit -f $TEMPDIR/cert-part -b %02d.pem -z "$CERTFILE" /-----BEGIN/ {*}

for CERT in $TEMPDIR/*.pem; do
  echo yes | keytool -import -file "$CERT" -alias "$CERT" -keystore "$KEYS
  " -storepass "$STOREPASS"
done

echo $TEMPDIR
}
```

Thanks to @Alex and @virag