# Can I use openssl s_client to retrieve the CA certificate for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, macos, ssl, openssl

Can I use `openssl s_client` to retrieve the CA certificate for MySQL?

I have access to the remote database server using the following

```
mysql -u theuser -h thehost --ssl --ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA -p thedatabase
```

Now I want to connect to it using JDBC.

I realize that I need to [insert the public certificate into my Java key store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27536391/266531). However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the public certificate. I realize it sits on the remote server in `/etc/mysql/ca.pem` or a similar place. But, I don't have permission to read that file or even `ssh` into the machine.

I've tried

```
openssl s_client -cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA  -connect thehost:3306
```

and some variations. I always get errors. For example

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
30495:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/BuildRoot/
Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:
```

Comment: Why doesn't the server have a CA-signed certificate?

Comment: ***`SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol...`*** - OpenSSL 0.9.8 does not support TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use openssl s_client to retrieve the CA certificate for MySQL?

You probably can't.

A well configured server will send the server certificate and all intermediate certificates required to build a path to the root CA. You have to have the root CA certificate already.

---

For example:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.cryptopp.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.cryptopp.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
...
```

The server sent the server's certificate. Its shown above as ***`0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=COMODO SSL Unified Communications`***. ***`S`*** means its the Subject, while ***`I`*** means its the issuer.

The server sent two intermediate certificates at ***`1`*** and ***`2`***. However, we need to have the Issuer of certificate 2 locally to build the path for validation. The Issuer of certificate 2 goes by the *Common Name* ***"AddTrust External CA Root"***.

"AddTrust External CA Root" can be downloaded from Comodo's site at [[Root] AddTrust External CA Root](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/917/91/)

It the server sent the root CA, then a bad guy could tamper with the chain and a client would be no wiser. They could swap-in their own CA and use an evil chain.

---

We can clear the ***`verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`*** by fetching the root CA, and then using ***`-CAfile`***:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.cryptopp.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.cryptopp.com \
  -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot.pem
```

It will result in a ***`Verify Ok (0)`***.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, OpenSSL version 1.1.1 (released on 11 Sep 2018) now supports fetching the server certificate from a MySQL server.

```
openssl s_client -starttls mysql -connect thehost:3306
```

Source: [answer by Paul Tobias](https://serverfault.com/a/931652/331760)

Comment: Tested and this command also works with MariaDB. Recommended to use a recent openssl version like the latest docker alpine: `docker run --rm alpine/openssl s_client -starttls mysql -connect  server_hostname:3306`