# How to configure SSL connection to MySQL hosted on Azure with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, azure, ssl

On Azure I have found 4 certificates:

```
ClearDB CA Certificate
Client Certificate
Client Private Key
Client Certificate Bundle(for Windows only)
```

I have created `trustStore` with ClearDB CA  like it was told here
[How to connect to a remote MySQL database via SSL using Play Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536380/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-via-ssl-using-play-framework)

```
keytool -import -alias mysqlServerCACert -file cleardb.pem -keystore truststore.jks
```

Set Systems properties like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

Added parameters to jdbc url

```
?useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=true
```

But I still get Exception

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I'm really confused. Which certificate I should use. What for are other certificates? 
Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

@OlegKuts, according to the ClearDB [FAQ](http://w2.cleardb.net/index.php/faqs/#dedicated_1) about enforce client SSL (or x.509) authentication as below, I think you should use the ClearDB CA certificate if it's got from ClearDB.

> **I need additional security options for my ClearDB cluster. How can I enforce client SSL (or x.509) authentication?**
>
> We operate our own CA, and we’ll be happy to generate x.509 user authentication certificates for your account. Please [send us a support request](http://w2.cleardb.net/index.php/contact) (login required) to get x.509 certificates.

Meanwhile, according to the ClearDB help & support [page](https://www.cleardb.com/help) (its link for Java is not available, but please see the rear MySQL 5.5 link), you need to follow the MySQL connector document [5.5 Connecting Securely Using SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) to try again.