# MySQL RDS and JDBC SSL connectivity giving error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, jdbc

I am trying to establish an SSL connection between JDBC and AWS RDS. Here I created a keystore using following commands:

```
# convert certificate into java understandable format
openssl x509 -outform der -in rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -out rds-combined-ca-bundle.der
# importing the certificate to keystore
sudo keytool -keystore keystore -alias rds_postgresql -import -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.der
```

And then set the value of keystore and keystore password directly into the application

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/of/the/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "******");
```

But, after adding all these settings, I am getting following error

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

What is wrong here?

I followed this tutorial to setup SSL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Comment: Please check if this helps! http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Comment: It might solve my problem but IMHO an extra component won't be a good solution. I guess finding the root cause may help me.

Comment: Please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536380/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-via-ssl-using-play-framework/52976082#52976082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` contains a bunch of certificates, if we split them and create `.pem` files for all certificates and import them to `keystore` separately, it will work.

The problem is caused because of importing the entire rds certificate bundle to keystore.